# How do you obtain the generating function from a summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have a solved exercise where in one step, they try to get the generating function of a summation (which has previously been obtained from a recurrence relation:$a_{n+1}-a_{n}= 3^n$, where $a_0 = 1$)and this happens:

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty  x^n3^n= \frac{x}{1-3x}$

They obtined it by:
1)Multiplying every term on the recurrence relation by $x^n$
2)Representing everything as various sumations $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^na_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^n3^n+\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^nn_{a-1}$

How do you obtain the generating function of a summation? Because I know that  $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^n= \frac{1}{1-x}$ but i don't know how to obtain  $\sum_{i=1}^n x^n3^n= \frac{x}{1-3x}$ from $\sum_{i=0}^\infty  x^n= \frac{1}{1-x}$. I must emphasize that I **know** that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty  x^n= \frac{1}{1-x}$ but I do not understand why nor how anything derived from it works. If I were presented with any summation different to the ones whose generating functions I know by hard, I would have nothing (that I know of) to do.

Comment: Hint: notice that $x^n3^n=(3x)^n$ and let $y=3x$ in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty y^n= \frac{1}{1-y}-1.$ (Beware, the upper limit is $\infty$, not $n$. And the index is $n$, not $i$.)

Comment: Your sums should have upper limit $\infty$, not $n$. Write out the series for $1/(1-x)$ as $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$. Substitute $3x$ for $x$. See what happens.

Comment: So much wrong here. It is true that: $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x^i3^i=\frac{3x}{1-3x},$$ but that is far from what you've written. $n$ is a constant, and $i$ varies, so $\sum_{i=1}^n x^n3^n=nx^n3^n.$  And the sum I've given goes to $\infty$ on the left and has a $3$ in the numerator.

Comment: "How do they get the generating function of a summation." That is a wrong use of words. Here, the sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 3^ix^i$ is the generating function of the sequence $a_0=0, a_i=3^i$ for $i>0.$ Generating functions are always "the generating function of a sequence." Do you want the generating function for $b_n=\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix^i?$

Comment: "And this happens." How did this happen? What does $a_n$ have to do with anything? And $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^n3^n$ is meaningless - it has to be $x^i3^i,$ or it isn't a generating function, and only ever converges when $x=0.$

Comment: It is entirely unclear, still, what you want. You say, "I don't know how to obtain..." and then state an equality which isn't true, so you'll never be able to obtain it.

Comment: [Here](https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/Combinatorics/Slides/Generating-Functions.pdf) is a good document on generating functions.